# CORS(Onelogin) request is not working in localhost

Tags: php, jquery

I used OneLogin User API to log a user in, without MFA, I tried to use the below function which makes cors request to onelogin.com.

```
function makeCors(session_token) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.withCredentials = true;
   method = "POST";
   var url = "https://admin.us.onelogin.com/mytoken";
   xhr.open(method, url, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   body = {"session_token": session_token};
   xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
 };
```

This gives the following error

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: If the recipient of a cross domain request does not include CORS headers in the response then you will not be able to make the call using JS.

Comment: Write a proxy on your server and let your jquery talk to the proxy

Comment: You can make this working by the alternative way,
    
    <form action=
     "https://admin.{us_or_eu}.onelogin.com/session_via_api_token" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="session_token" value="{your session token value}">
        <input type="submit" placeholder="GO">
        <input id="auth_token" type="hidden">
    </form>
    
    Submit this form on your page load.